# Unexpected date when ploting a timeseries MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time-series, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a `timeseries` using a cell array of strings representing an hour of measurements with a sample every 10 seconds. Below is the code I use to plot this data:

```
Voltages=[230.1,235.1,.......237];
Time={'13:00:10','13:00:20', '13:00:30'........'14:00:00'};

t=timeseries(Voltages, Time); % Using timeseries function in MATLAB

plot(t);
```

I also add two straight lines showing upper and lower voltage limits, and here is the chart I get:

[image: What I currently have]

As you can see in final result an unexpected date is shown on the x-axis ...

I want to do one of the following:

1. Remove the date altogether from the x-axis.
2. Using a date string `06.05.2015` I have in a variable, add this date instead of the 1-Jan-2015 unexpected date.
3. Remove the unexpected date from x-axis and then add the 06.05.2015 in text box.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`timeseries` class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html):

> `ts = timeseries(data,time)` creates the time-series object using the specified data and time.

Where `time` above is a "time vector" as defined [further down on the same documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html#bsplqwl):

> **Time Vector** 
> A time vector of a timeseries object can be either numerical (double) values or valid MATLAB date strings.
>
> **When the timeseries `TimeInfo.StartDate` property is empty, the numerical time values are measured relative to 0 (or another numerical value) in specified units. In this case, the time vector is described as relative (that is, it contains time values that are not associated with a specific start date).**

Before plotting the `timeseries`, try setting the `TimeInfo.StartDate` to what you need it to be, as shown in the example below:

```matlab
Time = ['13:00:10';'13:00:20';'13:00:30'];
Data = [1 2.5 3];
start_date = '06.05.2015'; %// What you specified

ts = timeseries(Data,Time);
%// Since a date format separated with dots isn't supported in MATLAB, we replace . => /
ts.TimeInfo.StartDate = strrep(start_date,'.','/');

plot(ts)
```

Which results in:

[image: result of the above plot]